# iOS app cannot connect to MobileFirst server

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

i created an hybrid application that should connect to the MFP and consume data.

When i try to connect to the Desktop Browser Application everything is fine and the app works. Same behaviour when i try the Mobile Web Application. BUT when i try to connect with the mobile native iOS application i could not connect and receive the following error (in the console):

```
2015-11-12 17:22:15.031 APPXYZ[6072:3089110] [FATAL] [NONE] Uncaught Exception: TypeError: WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.setConnected is not a function. (In 'WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.setConnected(false)', 'WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.setConnected' is undefined) at (compiled_code):3871
```

My specs:
 
    MFP version 7.1.0.00.20151107-1653
    Xcode 7.1.1
    iOS deploy target 8.0

Transport security protocol is deactivated (Allow Arbitrary Loads -> YES)

Comment: Provide the project....

Comment: which parts of the project you need ?

Comment: The generated native project should suffice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of my problem was that i change the init calling sequence of my app. I called the wl specific functions to early. After changing the sequence my app runs perfectly.....

thx 4 help :)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot confirm this claim.

Using the following, I create a blank new Hybrid app with the iPhone environment, that calls the WL.Client.connect method in `wlCommonInit()` and displays an alert with "success" or "failure" accordingly. I got "success". No errors in the Xcode Console.

Xcode 7.1.1
IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1.0.00-20151107-1647

If you are doing something different in your project, do let us know...